# Execute only a portion of the code if the page has already been opened previously

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

On Xamarin I created a `BottomNavigationBar`, inside it some buttons

```
<TabbedPage>
    <motivapp:MainPage Title="Home" IconImageSource="IC003.png"></motivapp:MainPage>
    <motivapp:DiaryPage Title="Diario" IconImageSource="ExpanderSmile.png"></motivapp:DiaryPage>
    <motivapp:NotePage Title="Appunti" IconImageSource="ExpanderWriting.png"></motivapp:NotePage>
    <motivapp:TimePage Title="Timer" IconImageSource="ExpanderTimer.png"></motivapp:TimePage>
</TabbedPage>
```

When I press on one of the buttons that opens another page to me, I would like to find a way to understand if it is the first time that I have opened that page since the app was opened or not. If this is the first time I would like it to execute all the code inside the initial constructor, otherwise only a part of it.

Comment: If your extra page can only exist once (you can't create more than one instance of it) you can just use a singleton. A simpler way is to just use a static property or member that holds a boolean and each time you instantiate check that bool and skip part of the constructor. The question is, what's your issue? What are you trying to fix, what does this code do in the constructor?

Comment: With that kind of BottomNavigationBar provided by Xamarin Essentials (if I remember correctly) there is no real Clicked event when pressed on the button, so I wouldn't know how to insert the boolean to change. What is the singleton instead?

Comment: Just set the boolean in the constructor, then you can just skip the code the next time the constructor is called.

Comment: yes, I find what you say correct, but how can I pass the boolean value between the various pages, to make it stay in memory, if I don't have a Clicked event in which to insert the boolean value between the constructor parameters?

Comment: Think you are missing the point of static members. Read up on static members. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#static-members